# How do I update SL Google Maps to EE2

Tags: ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades, google-maps

I am in the process of upgrading from EE1 to EE2. My EE1 site makes use of the SL Google Maps add-on, which does not seem to have an EE2 version. How do I handle this problem? Is there an add-on available for EE2 which allow me to upgrade relatively seamlessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've ported *SL Google Maps* to EE 2 by ourself, but ultimately switched to [*Google Maps for ExpressionEngine* from *Objective HTML*](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps) nonetheless after a few month of operating SL GM on EE2 and several Maps-API-changes made by Google.

I would recommend you to switch to *Objective HTMLs* Module too.

Answer (score 3):

The big daddy of googlemaps add-ons for EE2 is http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps but afaik there's no seamless upgrade path. You could contact objective html and ask though.

Answer (score 1):

Another Maps plugin I can easily recommend is [Gmaps](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps) - the developer is always updating it and keep improving the experience..